# React.js - componentDidMount not called when using renderComponentToString

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm setting html content to Twitter's Bootstrap popover like that.

```
var Content = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        alert('ok'); // not called
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>foobar</div>
        );
    }
});

var Button = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(this.getDOMNode()).popover({
            placement: 'right',
            trigger: 'manual',
            html: true,
            content: function() {
                return React.renderComponentToString(<Content />);
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-default">{this.props.name}</button>
        );
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        $(this.getDOMNode()).popover('toggle');
    }
});
```

For that, I could set the html content into popover, I must use the **renderComponentToString** method. Unfortunately, this method does not call the method **componentDidMount**. Why is this happend and how it can be solved? Thank you.

Comment: Reacts `componentDidMount` method is only called after the initial render  triggered by the `React.renderComponent` function.

The Content component is never mounted using that method so the `componentDidMount` method is never called.

I think what you're trying to do isn't possible using this method and there's probably a most appropriate method to achieve the result you are looking for.

Comment: Have you considered using [React Bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/)?

Comment: @cvrebert say that in an answer, and copy/paste a code snippet from their docs :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, code snippet from their docs does not work. I got warning: **Required prop 'container' was not specified in 'OverlayTrigger'**. What should be 'container'? Parent node? I did not find any mention of it in the documentation / examples.

Comment: I found only strange variable called 'mountNode' in last example. I tried to pass parent node into it, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted the [React-bootstrap docs](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) and got popovers to work this way:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var OverlayTrigger = ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger;
var Popover = ReactBootstrap.Popover;

var Content = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={<Popover title="Popover right"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.</Popover>}>
            <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        );
    }
});
```

Include react-bootstrap.js to get the globally accessible components. It's provided in the [bower package](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html).

And of course include React as well.